# Cocos2d-x - build for android error

Tags: cocos2d-x

So when I try to build my project for android I get this error:

```
 Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-15 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\MyGame\MyCppGame\proj.android../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk:cocos_freetype2_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/MyGame/MyCppGame/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/arm64-v8a/libfreetype.a exists or that its path is correct
make: Entering directory D:/MyGame/MyCppGame/proj.android'
D:/android-ndk/android-ndk-r12b/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting . Stop.
make: Leaving directoryD:/MyGame/MyCppGame/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

In fact there's no folder "arm64-v8a" there and I've tried to run it under a different (newer) sdk version still the same error. I've downloaded the 64bit NDK package. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to an older version of **NDK** such as 'ndk_r10c' or 'ndk_r10e' other than the latest version.

And It does not matter with sdk version. Just a warning.